# GWT Compilation

Tags: gwt, gwt-compiler

I am facing problem while GWT compilation. I am using ANT build file in which i run 'build' target. when execution comes to 'gwtc' target the compilation sometimes stop or somtime it compiles successfully. Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong ? 
I am using GWT2.0

Comment: What output do you get from ant when the compile 'stops'? By 'stops' do you mean terminates, or hangs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a GWT's app creator. Which solves problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HELLO zeeshan Brother

I got the answer!!!

1] Remove unused import from project

2] Don't Use server side object on client side

That's it

Your problem 100% Solve

Comment: Legend.  Belter of an answer.